# I want to display Account Team members of an account from lightning action on a mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Apex Class :

```
public with sharing class Instruments_showAccountTeamMembers 

    {
        @AuraEnabled
        public static list<AccountTeamMember> getRelatedList(Id recordId)
        {
            List<AccountTeamMember> atmlist = [Select Id, TeamMemberRole,AccountId,UserId
                                               from AccountTeamMember where AccountId=: recordId ];
            return atmlist;
        }
    }
```

Lightning COmponent :

```
<aura:component controller = "Instruments_showAccountTeamMembers" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction " access="global" >
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="AccountTeamMemberList" type="AccountTeamMember[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getAtm}" />
    <aura:iteration  items="{!v.AccountTeamMemberList}" var="atm">
        AccountTeamMember Name = {!atm.UserId} <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

js:

```
({
 getAtm : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var atmlist = component.get("c.getRelatedList");
        atmlist.setParams
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });

        atmlist.setCallback(this, function(data) 
                           {
                               component.set("v.AccountTeamMemberList", data.getReturnValue());
                           });
        $A.enqueueAction(atmlist);
 }
})
```

But it gives me the error : Error while creating component for lightning component quick action [Unable to find action 'getAtm' on the controller of c:Instruments_showAccountTeamMembers]

Comment: I have tried the same code in my org and it is working fine for both mobile and desktop.

Comment: are u able to get all the account team members related to account ?

Comment: Yes, I have got